# How much do certain probiotics reduce cavity causing bacteria?

Tags: nutrition, diet, dentistry, treatment, experiment

In the paper titled [Effect of Short-term Consumption of Amul Probiotic Yogurt Containing *Lactobacillus acidophilus* La5 and *Bifidobacterium* Lactis Bb12 on Salivary *Streptococcus* mutans Count in High Caries Risk Individuals](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5932918/)

I am having trouble deciphering the degree of difference between the probiotics used and controls (I am no scientist but like to read studies). Here are the highlights which I think discuss the effectiveness:

> Mauchly's test of sphericity for the case group showed that there were significant differences between the “variance of differences” of the S. mutans count at baseline, 2 weeks and 4 weeks as a result the readings were subjected to Hyunh and Feldt's test to compare difference in *S. mutans* count during the 4-week period which was of highly significant value, *F* (1.664, 34.000) = 169.607, *P* = 0.000. Thus, a pairwise comparison was done further that showed a significant difference of *S. mutans* between the baseline and 1st follow-up and also 1st and 2nd follow-up with a *P* value of 0.000. The difference of count was not significant between baseline and 2nd follow-up.
>
> Mauchly's Test of Sphericity for the control group showed that there were no significant differences between the “variance of differences” of the *S. mutans* count at baseline, 2 weeks and 4 weeks in control group. As a result, the readings were subjected to Wilks Lambda test which suggested that there was no significant difference of the *S. mutans* count during the 4 weeks period. Thus, a pair-wise comparison was not done in control group.
>
> Table 3 shows the effect of time and interaction between time and intervention on *S. mutans* count in all the study participants. The effect was observed using Hyunh and Feldt's correction and a significant difference was observed in the *S. mutans* count as the time passed, *F* (1.663, 113.117) = 164.780, *P* = 0.000 and also there was a significant effect of interaction between the time and intervention on *S. mutans* count, *F* (1.663, 113.117) = 168.899, *P* = 0.000."